# What's with the dark side of the moon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Usually I see real moon phases in minecraft. Half moon, Crescent moon, Full moon, ect.

Tonight, I see this.

[image]

What gives? An Eclipse isn't likely, as the moon is progressing through the sky WITH the darkside matching its pace, rather than going in the opposite direction.

Comment: Uh, it's a new moon?

Comment: Minecraft in some ways is very beautiful and unique!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could as well ask, "why is the moon square?"

Minecraft is simply not realistic; you can't expect it to be scientifically correct.

This is just a phase of the moon, called "new moon", made by the developers as accurately as they could or wanted to.

Comment: Correct. This phase, more specifically, is the "New" Moon.

Comment: [Phases of the moon](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Moon#Phases_of_the_Moon) in a GIF animation. Interestingly, the moon's terminator is curved during waxing and waning, which means the moon must be a tide-locked dome with a square base.

Comment: In practical terms, making the moon have a visible border instead of being just a patch of starless black makes it easier to locate when figuring out the time at night, and is probably intentional.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Ha! I hadn't thought of the whole curve/square conflict.